# Sort values in column and return max repeated items in list

Tags: c#, sorting

I have the picture as following:

[image]

I would like to do two task as bellow:

- First one: Sort the values in column TOTAL from smallest to largest
- Second one: Input the number records need to select (e.g: 4 records) and return max item which it is repeated in list

Here my code but it is not work.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customersBindingSource.DataSource = new List<Customers>();          

    }               
    private void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        int k;
        string temp;             
        //Step 1: Sort values smallest to largest on TOTAL column
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataView dv = new DataView();
        dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = dv.Table.Columns[3].ColumnName + "ASC";
        dt = dv.Table;
        //Step 2: Input k rows & return max repeated items in list of Column 1 (BOOK_NAME)
        k = Convert.ToInt32(txtkvalue.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            temp = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            List<string> prod = new List<string>();
            prod.Add(temp);
            var grouped = prod.ToLookup(x => x);
            var maxRepetitions = grouped.Max(x => x.Count());
            var maxRepeatedItems = grouped.Where(x => x.Count() == maxRepetitions)
                                          .Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
            //MessageBox.Show(maxRepeatedItems.ToString());
        }            
    }
```

The expected result (k=4):

- Sort (TOTAL column): 150, 200, 200, 250, 300
- Return Book name: Book 2 (list: Book 1, Book 2, Book 2, Book 3)

Please help to advise for me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Isaac I edited my answer little bit, so you undestand what is behind. Hope it's understandable

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich: Thank you for your advise but It also can't run and show the message at the line :var ordered = baseList.OrderBy(e => e.Total); --> 
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'

Comment: If you just simply copied the code and run it, then yeah, you get that error. Do you see what is on the first line? Although the `baseList` is initialized, there is a comment saying that *you* need to implement gathering data from your datasource. In it's current form, you can compile it, but it will not run without exception. Here on SO people will guide you to correct direction, but nobody will do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you will have data structure for keeping values like this:

```
class Customers
{
    public int ID {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public double Price {get; set; }
    public double Total {get; set; }
}
```

Then you are searching for the queries:

```
List<Customers> baseList = null;// TODO get data

// order by Total
var ordered = baseList.OrderBy(e => e.Total);

// get first n rows:
var nRows = baseList.Take(n);

// get name of the most repeated element
var max = nRows.GroupBy(e => e.Name).OrderByDescending( e => e.Count()).FirstOrDefault()?.Key;
```

To describe what is happening in the third query: you take a collection and group it by name. Grupped structures then will be {Name, [all rows having Name] }. Then you just order it (descending) by number of items in each grup. Last step is to take first item from that collection (it could be empty, if you run it on empty input collection) and get it's name. Since I used `FirstOrDefault`, I used `?.` operator, which will behave correctly when trying to use property on `NULL` object. It is basically a syntactic sugar.

I'd advise you to split this logic and following rendering (in this case into a table) logic. Just keep somewhere base data and when you need to update yor view table, run desired queries and then simply set results to your Table. Trying to set data to datatable and then obtain them again and do some logic on them - this approach is slow and will do no good.